# Sidebar is appearing on custom post pages without being called

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a Wordpress theme for a graphic portfolio website, and I'm utilizing the sidebar.php for a hero image on the index page that is not meant to appear on other pages. While this works for all static inside pages, I have two custom post categories, and the sidebar section has started appearing above those posts.

I should note that this hasn't always been a problem, and started cropping up for no apparent reason while working on something else.

On index.php, the sidebar is called as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile; ?>
<nav>
<ul class="pager">
<li><?php next_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?></li>
<li><?php previous_posts_link( 'Next' ); ?></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<?php endif;?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

While page.php is similar but lacks the php line calling the sidebar, as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile; endif;?>
</div> <!-- /.col -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

page-fine-art.php also lacks that php line, as follows:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<?php
$args =  array(
'post_type' => 'fine-art',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="blog-post">
<h2 class="blog-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?      php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p class="blog-post-meta"><?php the_date(); ?> by <a href="#"><?php    the_author(); ?></a></p>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
} ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div> <!-- /.col -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The function creating the the custom posts for "fine art" goes:

```
function create_my_custom_posts() {
register_post_type( 'fine-art',
array(
'labels' => array(
'name' => __( 'Fine Art' ),
'singular_name' => __( 'Fine Art' ),
),
'public' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'supports' => array(
'title',
'editor',
'thumbnail',
'custom-fields'
)
));
```

I don't see where sidebar.php is being called in the final example, or where else it could be coming from.

Comment: If you run the command `grep -r 'get_sidebar()'` in your theme's folder, do any other files pop up that use this function?

Comment: Mr Me - I'm new to terminal and couldn't get the folder path to work, however,  did look through all files in the folder and confirmed the function is only in index.php and nowhere else. Also cut and replaced the offending code and refreshed twice - disappeared in all places without it in the index, back on the custom post pages when I put it back.